# Multiple if-conditions AWK

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk

I have a very big file with german postalcodes/zipcodes. For each code I want to find the correct federal state. What I did is the following.

1. I printed the zipcodes in a new file.
2. I sorted them and kicked out double cases.
   Now I had a new file with 2267 different zipcodes.
3. I created a awk command which should find one name for each code.

looking like this:

```
{if ($1 >= 01001 && $1 <=01936) 
print "Sachsen" >"PLZ6.txt"} 
{if ($1 >= 01941 && $1 <= 01998) 
print "Brandenburg" >"PLZ6.txt"}
{if ($1 >= 02601 && $1 <= 02999)
print "Sachsen" >"PLZ6.txt"}
{if ($1 >= 03001 && $1 <= 03253)
print "Brandenburg" >"PLZ6.txt"} #this goes on for another 150 different lines...
```

So I thought I get one name for exactly one zipcode (if it falls in the range of the condition). That means I should have exactly 2267 cases in my new file. However, my new file as 23k cases.

I wonder, if the zip code falls into multiple ranges...Do you have any idea, why the zipcode could fit into several conditions? I want to have every zipcode matching exactly one condition.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Here is how most users would probably agree the site works: you don't need to greet or thank in advance, avoiding these words makes your question easier to scan so that the right person can answer it (also they won't make sense months from now when someone else has the same problem and reads it your question). If your question is on-topic, you don't need to apologize for asking it. If it is not on-topic, the community will let you know anyway.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to say with certainty since I don't know the whole script or the whole input data, but I strongly suspect that it is related to your unintentional use of octal numbers. In awk, literals that start with `0` and don't contain `8` or `9` are octal numbers, which is to say that `010 == 8`, `0100 == 64` etc. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nondecimal_002dnumbers.html) for details.

When you write

```
{if ($1 >= 01001 && $1 <=01936)
```

then `01001` is an octal number and `01936` is a decimal number (with GNU awk, at least, because it contains a `9`), so you're asking whether `$1 >= 513 && $1 <= 1936`.

My suspicion is that you have, in this way, constructed overlapping ranges, and that the problem could be fixed by removing the leading zeroes from all conditions (since the octal interpretation does not apply to the input data).

By the way, it would arguably be more awkish to write

```
$1 >= 1001 && $1 <= 1936 { print "Sachsen" > "PLZ6.txt" }
```

and so forth.

Comment: That one really did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

@Wintermute is probably correct wrt the octal guess. If so accept his answer but either way rewrite your code as:

```
function m(beg,end,state) {
    if ( ($1 >= beg) && ($1 <= end) ) {
        if ($1 in states) {
            printf "Warning: State for zip \"%s\" being changed from \"%s\" to \"%s\".\n", $1, states[$1], state| "cat>&2"
        }
        states[$1] = state
        print state > "PLZ6.txt"
    }
}
{
    m(1001,1936,"Sachsen") 
    m(1941,1998,"Brandenburg")
    m(2601,2999,"Sachsen")
    m(3001,3253,"Brandenburg")
}
```

and once you have identified and fixed any remaining issues with your zip codes add a `next` statement to the end of the `m()` function to significantly improve the efficiency of your code:

```
function m(beg,end,state) {
    if ( ($1 >= beg) && ($1 <= end) ) {
        if ($1 in states) {
            printf "Warning: State for zip \"%s\" being changed from \"%s\" to \"%s\".\n", $1, states[$1], state| "cat>&2"
        }
        states[$1] = state
        print state > "PLZ6.txt"
        next
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, the file which contains the postalcode should be looking as below:

```
01001 City-Name Sachsen
01936 City-Name Sachsen
02601 City-Name Sachsen
02602 City-Name Sachsen
02603 City-Name Sachsen
02604 City-Name Sachsen
02999 City-Name Sachsen
01941 City-Name Brandenburg
01942 City-Name Brandenburg
01943 City-Name Brandenburg
01944 City-Name Brandenburg
01945 City-Name Brandenburg
01998 City-Name Brandenburg
03001 City-Name Brandenburg
03253 City-Name Brandenburg
```

Here replace the `City-Name` with the actual city name of the postalcode. To to get the federal state of that pincode you can do a simple pattern search like

```
$ awk '/01945/ {print $3}' postalcodes.txt
Brandenburg
```

This should give you the federal state. Did this solve your problem ?